# Как удалить произвольный элемент из стэка в Java?

Tags: java, стек

***без использования класса Stack***

Стэк создается без проблем, добавляет/удаляет сверху, а вот при попытке удалить произвольный нивкакую не хочет работать,
 модификация метода deleteElement ничего не выдает

```
 public int deleteElementS(**int d**) {
        return stackArray[top-d]; //чтобы удалить каждый второй
    }
```

Подобная модификация намертво вешает программу  (вечно выводит второй элемент)

```
public int deleteElement() {
        return stackArray[top-1];
    }
public int deleteElements(int d) {
        for(int i=top+1-d;i<top;i++)
            stackArray[i] = stackArray[i + 1];
        return top--;
    }
```

Stack.java

```
class Stack {
    private int mSize;
    private int[] stackArray;
    private int top;

    public Stack(int m) {
        this.mSize = m;
        stackArray = new int[mSize];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void addElement(int element) {
        stackArray[++top] = element;
    }

    public int deleteElement() {
        return stackArray[top--];
    }


    public int readTop() {
        return stackArray[top];

    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (top == -1);
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return (top == mSize - 1);
    }
}
```

main.java

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack mStack = new Stack(10);

        mStack.addElement(4);
        mStack.addElement(3);
        mStack.addElement(2);
        mStack.addElement(1);

        mStack.deleteElements(3);

        System.out.print("Стек: ");
        while (!mStack.isEmpty()) {
            int value = mStack.deleteElement();
            System.out.print(value);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать [Collection.Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)? Или если хотите сами написать, можете наследоваться от [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

Comment: Нельзя его использовать по заданию, так бы все было куда проще =)

Comment: Если из коллекции можно удалить произвольный элемент, то эта коллекция не стек.

Comment: @GideonSTL так наследуйтесь от Vector, там многие методы уже не нужно писать. Или это тоже не нельзя?

Comment: Увы, нельзя. Потому и сижу уже неделю голову ломаю

Comment: @GideonSTL почему тогда нельзя скопипастить стек из коллекций/скопипастить стек со статей? В гугле куча статей, [первая ссылка](https://javadevblog.com/pishem-stek-na-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

Задача сводится к удалению элемента из массива. Шаги для этого:

Проверить, что такой элемент существует:

```
 if (top + 1 -d <= 0)
    return -1;
```

Вернуть значение  с индексом `[top-d]` или `[top + 1 -d]` (т.к. не уточнено - последний считается нулевым или первым)

Сдвинуть влево элементы массива после удаляемого

```
 for(int i=top+1-d;i<top;i++) 
    stackArray[i] = stackArray[i + 1];
```

Уменьшить счётчик `top--`

Comment: Не помогло, просто пустой экран
public int deleteCelement(int d) {
        for(int i=top+1-d;i<top;i++)
            stackArray[i] = stackArray[i + 1];
        return top--;
    }

Comment: Я ваш экран, а главное -  код , как реализовали. как используется - не вижу. Отладку используйте.

Comment: Как используется этот метод?

Comment: имя_метода(номер_удаляемого) ,я думал так

Comment: Код вопроса отредактируйте, покажите, как в главной программе оно вызывается

Comment: Воткнул код в исходный

Comment: А вот это сейчас используется? `public int deleteElement() {  return stackArray[top-1];`

Comment: Нет не используется, это первоначальный вариант удаления "сверху"

Comment: А в main что делается теперь? И проверку нужно ввести, что элементов хватает

Comment: Ничего не делалось от слова совсем, но по старому доброму завету вырезал-вставил и (удивительно) все заработало, спасибо - вы волшебник :))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, кидать все элементы в другой стек (за исключением того, который нужно удалить, а потом перекинуть все элементы нового стека обратно (восстановить последовательность элементов)